# Sequential search in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, sql-update, traversal

I am trying to search values from another table and if any of the 6-7 columns have a different value then i am inserting them into the existing table and changing the flags.

Is there a specific way to search faster or should I use sequential search? Not sure how this works in SQL

For example:

Table A

```
A B C D Flg
1 2 3 4 N 
2 1 4 3 N
3 3 2 1 N
4 4 1 2 N
5 2 1 2 N
1 3 3 4 Y --(flg changed because values in column B changed)
```

the logic traverses through the table to find when values change and then updates the Flag and inserts those values into another table.

Comment: try using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms189788.aspx

Comment: can you explain the logic? I see all column are changing values not only column2.

Comment: In the above example, Column A is a treated as a primary key (not literally) so whenever there are duplicates in column A, I will check if there any changes in the column values and then mark the Ch_Flg as Y and insert a new record with latest values in the same table

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow where the data is coming from or which table is receiving it. If you're just dealing with one row at a time and it needs to be in a self-contained `insert` then perhaps this is what you need.

```
;with MyData(A, B, C, D) as (
    select * from (values (1, 3, 3, 4)) as v
)
insert into Table1 (A, B, C, D, Flg)
select A, B, C, D, 'Y'
from MyData as d
where not exists (
    select 1 from Table2 as t
    where t.A = d.A and t.B = d.B and t.C = d.C and t.D = d.D
);
```

I have a hunch that there's probably a much cleaner way to do this than whatever method you've got rigged up already.